# Unable to find the container dom element fusion chart

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fusioncharts

I tried to follow the fusionchart tutorial to create my first chart but I get this error "Unable to find the container DOM element". I don't know where it comes from. Could someone help me? Thank you in advance for your help

```
<script>
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueFusionCharts from 'vue-fusioncharts';
import FusionCharts from 'fusioncharts';
import Column2D from 'fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts';
import FusionTheme from 'fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion';

Vue.use(VueFusionCharts, FusionCharts, Column2D, FusionTheme);

const chartData = [...];

const dataSource = {
  chart: {
    caption: "Countries With Most Oil Reserves [2017-18]",
    subcaption: "In MMbbl = One Million barrels",
    xaxisname: "Country",
    yaxisname: "Reserves (MMbbl)",
    numbersuffix: "K",
    theme: "fusion"
  },
  data: chartData
  };

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data() {
    return {
      "type": "column2d",
      "renderAt": "chart-container",
      "width": "550",
      "height": "350",
      "dataFormat": "json",
      dataSource
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="chart-container">
      <fusioncharts
      :type="type"
      :width="width"
      :height="height"
      :dataformat="dataFormat"
      :dataSource="dataSource"
      >
      </fusioncharts>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the package's docs and I couldn't dins anything about your "renderAt" property. Maybe try omitting this property?

Answer (score 0):

FusionCharts needs a container to render the charts, since it's not getting the container hence the error is showing.

You have to provide a chart container inside your page. Normally it is a div. You have already provided the chart container id as "chart-1" inside the constructor parameter. So adding the following div to the page  will solve the problem

```
    <template>
  <div id="chart-container"></div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    chartType: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    width: {
      type: String,
      default: "100%"
    },
    height: {
      type: String,
      default: "400"
    },
    dataSource: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    dataFormat: "json"
  }),
  mounted() {
    this.render();
  },
  methods: {
    render() {
      const fusionChart = new FusionCharts({
        type: this.chartType,
        width: this.width,
        height: this.height
      });

      fusionChart.setJSONData(this.dataSource);
      fusionChart.render(this.$root.$el.querySelector("#chart-container"));
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

So, you can use the component above and inject dataSource via props, e.g. `<FusionChart chart-type="doughnut2d" :data-source="dataSource" />`